# Quering Friend/Blog database with Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, relation

I'm making a social media kind of website, where people can post messages and become friends and such.

And so I have a database with the following tables.

Friends

```
+-----+-----------+----------+----------+--------+
| id  | Bevriend  | UserID1  | UserID2  | vType  |
+-----+-----------+----------+----------+--------+
|  1  |        1  |       1  |       3  |      0 |
+-----+-----------+----------+----------+--------+
```

Blog

```
+-----+----------------+-------+---------+
| id  |     title      | text  | userid  |
+-----+----------------+-------+---------+
|  1  | My first entry | Test  |       1 |
+-----+----------------+-------+---------+
```

I want to write a query of sorts to get the blog posts only from the person I am friends with.
So long as either UserID1 or UserID2 contains the userID from my session AND in the database the bit known as "Bevriend" is set to 1 it should get the records.

I am at a loss, if I need to supply you with more information please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am giving you a query that might help. It takes only items from blog which are posted by friend, but not current user. You query should look like (excluding blog posts where the current user is the author):

```
SELECT
    b.*
FROM Blog b
INNER JOIN Friends f ON (b.userid = f.UserID1 OR b.userid = f.UserID2)
WHERE
    f.Bevriend = 1
AND
(
    b.userid = f.UserID1 AND f.UserID2 = '{$currentUserID}'
OR
    b.user_id = f.UserID2 AND f.UserID1 = '{$currentUserID}'
)
```

What we do here is to JOIN the table this way that either `UserID1` or `UserID2` appear as Blog record "owner". Then in the where clause we say *give me only these blog records where **where the owner is my friend and not me***, for each column `UserID1` and `UserID2`.

This should look like in CI (including the blog posts where current user is the author):

```
$currentUserID = (int) $this->session->userdata('userID');
$page = (int) $this->input->get('page'); // example retrieving of desired page num
$pagesize = (int) $this->config->item('blog_pagesize'); // example retrieving of pagesize

// Prevent unexpected behavior
if(0 >= $page)
    $page = 1;

// Prevent unexpected behavior
if(0 >= $pagesize)
    $pagesize = 20; // If config is wrong we ensure it will continue to work

// Additional page checks go here...

$query = $this->db->query('
    SELECT
        b.*
    FROM Blog b
    INNER JOIN Friends f ON (b.userid = f.UserID1 OR b.userid = f.UserID2)
    WHERE
        f.Bevriend = 1
    AND
    ( f.UserID2 = ? OR UserID1 = ?)
    LIMIT ?, ?
', array($currentUserID, $currentUserID, ($page - 1) * $pagesize, $pagesize));

 foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
     echo $row->id;
     echo $row->title;
     echo $row->text;
 }

 // Clean up at the end
 $query->free_result();
```

You could adapt the columns you want to retrieve, ordering and remove duplications with GROUP BY or DISTINCT. We run custom query here, because is much more cleaner that using `$this->db->select`, `$this->db->from`, `$this->db->join`,`$this->db->where`, etc. when the query got more complex. If you use them you have to pass third paramater `true` to disable each of these functions escaping and it will look like "ugly code".

You cannot use pagination directly with custom query through `$this->db->query`. This is because it is CI query, but not an active record. Below I translate the query into active record one.

To use the default CI active record functionality:

```
$results = $this->db->select('b.*')
     ->from('Blog b')
     ->join('Friends f', 'b.userid = f.UserID1 OR b.userid = f.UserID2')
     ->where('f.Bevriend', 1)
     ->where("(f.UserID1 = {$currentUserID} OR f.UserID2 = {$currentUserID})")
     ->group_by('b.id')
     //->get()
     //->results();
```

The example above should enable you to use the default pagination, although I find it not very useful and flexible.

Comment: You *SHOULD* replace `{$currentUserID}` with `?`! Beside, you're using single quotes, so `{$currentUserID}` won't work anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot! only a few problems, since I also have a limit and start for the pagination where do they go? And how do i execute the query in a way that I can pass the results back to my view?

Comment: Yes cause I copy paste it from the plain SQL part. I already have written for ?

Comment: They go on the very end of the query.

Comment: @user3518404, see my edited post for LIMIT clause. It is example code.

Comment: There is just one more thing, It doesnt show me my own blog posts :S Thanks in advance, you've all been wonderfull!

Comment: Check in CI code the sql. Sorry but mobile stack overflow crash and brake formatting

Comment: Just remove the check with b.UserID in between OR.

Comment: And finally, it works.. almost that is :P It shows the records double since i dont have a group by clause, and since this query is a bit out of my reach i really can't tell what i should do, and besides that my pagination isn't working correctly. It only shows 5 results, and when in try to go to my second page, it's empty.

Comment: I will edit it in about 20 min when I will reach a PC, use `group by b.id` before the limit clause.

Comment: The group by works like a charm, still no second page though, I use the built in functions from codeigniter, which sets a config. If you need any info I'll edit it in my original post!

Comment: The $page variable is example. It should contain the page you are referring to. The pagesize is the the number of items you want to display per each page, its also an example how to retrieve it. What do you mean built-in functions to set a config?

Comment: [link](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html) I use this method to create pagination

Comment: @user3518404, check the answer now. I have added same implementation with active record statement. You can use it to paginate with the default library.